# PHP Laravel | Testing Polymorphic Many To Many | If Statement not working correctly

Tags: laravel, if-statement, routes, polymorphism, many-to-many

So I'm not having a huge problem but I did notice something that did not work and I can't explain why. The issue is within the route as I'm just learning and messing around with Polymorphic Relations and what not.

Keep in mind all data is seeded and I have verified there is proper data in the fields by manually inserting comments and making sure the show up.

Here's my web.php file.

```
Route::get('/get/{id}/post', function($id) {
  $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  foreach($user->posts as $post) {
    echo "<hr /><h2>" . $post->title . "</h2>";
    echo "<p>By: ". $post->users->name ." | Date:" . $post->created_at->format('n-j-Y');
    echo "<br />" . $post->content . "</p><hr />";
    echo "<h3>Comments</h3>";
    if(!empty($post->comments)) {
      foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
        echo "<u>" . $comment->users->name . "</u><br />" . $comment->content . "<br /><br />";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Sorry there are no comments yet.";
    }
  }
});
```

The Problem I'm having is within the if statement at the bottom it does in fact pull all the comments and the Users name when comments exist. The real problem is that when there are no comments its not showing the else statement echo.

I find this really weird become I come to find it works if I'm just outputting one single post but not if I pull multiple post for that user.

Any Ideas why this would do this I'm really confused. Thanks!

I got it to work with a collection method like so.

```
if($post->comments->isNotEmpty()) {
  foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
    echo "<u>" . $comment->users->name . "</u><br />" . $comment->comment . "<br /><br />";
  }
} else {
  echo "Sorry there are no comments yet.";
}
```

Anyone know the reason though behind why I can't use the !empty() function?

Comment: Did you tried with isEmpty()? AFAIK it should return Collection instance, so simple empty wont cut it
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isempty
Try this instead and see if it helps ;) or for your case `isNotEmpty`

Comment: Thanks worked totally didn't even think of using a collection method. I'm surprised though I thought it would work the same. Interesting still makes me wonder the reason behind it not working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried with isEmpty()? AFAIK it should return Collection instance, so simple empty won't cut it [Laravel 5.6 collections method-isempty](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isempty) Try this instead and see if it helps ;) or for your case `isNotEmpty`

> Anyone know the reason though behind why I can't use the !empty() function?

Because Collection is an Object therefore variable is not [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) 
For that reason Collection object has a functions `isEmpty()` `isNotEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a collection method like so. Thanks to Vaida Lungis for suggesting to use a collection method from laravel here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isempty

```
if($post->comments->isNotEmpty()) {
  foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
    echo "<u>" . $comment->users->name . "</u><br />" . $comment->comment . "<br /><br />";
  }
} else {
  echo "Sorry there are no comments yet.";
}
```

Also hopefully someone can answer the other small part of my question at the bottom.